# ImageModel form problem

Tags: django

I'm trying to upload an image from a form. I'm using ImageModel with the User as a foreign key, I'm having trouble with the form . any help will be highly appreciated, please, thanks

Comment: What trouble are you having? Do you have some code you can show us that's not working - and even better, can you explain exactly in what way it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your form tag contains `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and that you bind your form to `request.POST, request.FILES`

views.py:

```
some_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = myForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        ....
```

template.html:

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
...
```

Comment: <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> would be better ;)

Comment: Yes I believe that would be much better, I'll fix the answer